# data.table index of subset

Tags: r, data.table

Working with `data.table` package in R, I'm trying to get the 'group number' of some data points.
Specifically, my data is trajectories: I have many rows describing a specific observation of the particle I'm tracking, and I want to generate a specific index for the trajectory based on other identifying information I have.
If I do a `[, , by]` command, I can group my data by this identifying information and isolate each trajectory.
Is there a way, similar to `.I` or `.N`, which gives what I would call the index of the subset?

Here's an example with toy data:

```
dt <- data.table(x1 = c(rep(1,4), rep(2,4)),
x2 = c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2),
z = runif(8))
```

I need a fast way to get the trajectories (here should be `c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4)` for each observation -- my real data set is moderately large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we need the `trajectories` (donno what that means) based on the 'x2', we can use `rleid`

```
dt[, Grp := rleid(x2)]
```

Or if we need the group numbers based on 'x1' and 'x2', `.GRP` can be used.

```
dt[,  Grp := .GRP,.(x1, x2)]
```

Or this can be done using `rleid` alone without the `by` (as @Frank mentioned)

```
dt[, Grp := rleid(x1,x2)]
```

Comment: `.GRP` is probably more intuitive for me but both work